# Prevent a JWindow to remain always on top

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe, always-on-top

I created a `JFrame` and and a `JWindow`. My problem is that when I click on another application my `JFrame` passes behind the application but not my `JWindow` which remains always on top.
I tried to call `setAlwaysOnTop(false)` on my `JWindow` but this doesn't change anything.
I would like that the `JWindow` "follows" the `JFrame.`

Here's my test code:

```
public class WindowAlwaysOnTop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        final JWindow window = new JWindow(frame);
        window.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        window.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no specific issues with your code.

Comment: @paranoia25 Tested it using JDK7 and it ran fine for me.

Comment: Thx! You're right. Working with JDK7 instead of jre 1.6.0_32 6solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred with JRE 1.6.0_32 and is solved with JDK7.

Comment: JRE is not the development environment. If you used a JRE it shouldn't work at all. JDK is what you are after. p.s. Just ran your code with JDK6u40 and it ran fine

Comment: Is that supposed to be an answer?  It looks like it should be an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15001356/edit).

Comment: I can remove the answer and edit the comment. No problem. But in this case I can't mark this question as resolved, can I?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a JWindow.

Instead use a JDialog. Just make sure you specify the frame as the parent when you create the dialog. You can use an undecorated dialog if you don't like the titlebar.

Comment: I have think to this solution. But in my case it doesn't match with my problem: I must have a window on top of a frame and see the frame through the window. And I must display dialog on top of the window! And I must to be sure that of this exact stack order: the dialog is on top of the window which is on top of the frame...